# Double Pointer C for List

Tags: c, list, null, double-pointer

A short time ago I began to learn c. When I tried coding list I wrote function with double pointer because I saw this in other resource, then I by myself finished writing this function and it's didn't work, please help me and explain how this work.

```
void
push(v_stack_t ** node, int num_args, ...)
{

    va_list ap;
    v_stack_t **current = node;

    va_start(ap, num_args);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_args; i++) {
        v_stack_t *new_node = (v_stack_t *) malloc(sizeof(v_stack_t));
        new_node->value = va_arg(ap, int);

        if (*current == NULL) {
            *current = new_node;
            continue;
        }
        while ((*current)->next != NULL) {
            current = &(*current)->next;
        }
        (*current)->next = new_node;
    }
    va_end(ap);
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do and what is not working.
Is your problem with the varargs part (va_ functions) or with the v_stack_t data structure? In the second case, can you show that data structure

Comment: Before current = &(*current)->next; I had *current = (*current)->next; and I don't understand why we should write this.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown us the definition for `v_stack_t`, but you do not initialize all the members of that struct after you allocate one.  `new_node->next` will have some unknown value in it (likely not NULL), causing problems when you try to add a second node.  You should set

```
new_node->next = NULL;
```

right after the `malloc` statement.

Unrelated, you don't need to cast the return value from `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

As *1201ProgramAlarm* mentioned, you need to set `next` to `NULL`.

But, because you use `current`, its final value is never propagated back to caller (e.g. you'd need to set `*node` at the end).

Your inner `while` loop could be moved above your outer loop.

And, it's far easier to dereference `node` at the beginning and use single indirect pointers for the bulk of the function.  *Side note:* `head` is more descriptive of function than `node` here.

Here's a rework of your code:

```
void
push(v_stack_t **head, int num_args, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    v_stack_t *tail;

    // find last element of list
    tail = NULL;
    for (v_stack_t *cur = *head;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next)
        tail = cur;

    va_start(ap, num_args);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_args; i++) {
        v_stack_t *new_node = malloc(sizeof(v_stack_t));

        new_node->value = va_arg(ap, int);
        new_node->next = NULL;

        // append to tail of list
        if (tail != NULL)
            tail->next = new_node;

        // add node at head of list
        else
            *head = new_node;

        // set new element as tail of list
        tail = new_node;
    }
    va_end(ap);
}
```